# How to get the current url in xslt

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, xslt-1.0

I'm programing in sharepoint and I need to get the current url in my Content Query WebPart's Sytle file(ItemStyle.xsl or ContentQueryMain.xsl) in order to add the querystring to the url of a link in my pages.

> Is it possible to get the URL of the page in XSL similar to javascript's location.href ?

Comment: Not in XSLT 1.0. However, you can pass this URL as a parameter to the transformation and use this parameter inside the transformation.

Comment: How to pass the parameter to the transformation? It is my first time to use xSLT for customizing the CQWP

Comment: The way to pass external parameters to the transformation is implementation-dependent. I suspect that Sharepoint uses the .NET XslCompiledTransform. If so, you need to read this about XsltArgumentList.AddParam(): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addparam.aspx  However, if it uses MSXML, then you need to read the related MSXML documentation. Also, Sharepoint itself may have a wrapper around the XSLT processor and its own rules for passing parameters -- again, you need to read the relevant Sharepoint documentation.

Answer (score 3):

try This

We will be adding this namespace to your XSL file, you can add it to either Main CQWP xsl or ItemStyle.xsl, incase you add it to Main XSL pass it down to Item Template as parameter.  I usually add to Item Style XSL .

Add NameSpace xmlns:ddwrt=”http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime” at top
Add a parameter “PageUrl “   right below your namespace definitions

1. Concat this parameter as part in your Display URL as part Source query string parameter

Thanks

Comment: Can it get the current url?